# Can a background thread trigger a message handler on UI thread in android

Tags: android

I have a thread which is started in `onCreate()` and this thread fetches some data.
Is it possible that before the thread is terminated should be able to update the `ListView`?

Now as the thread is not the UI thread, it cannot directly update the listview array adapter.

Is there a way out?
I was thinking that is it possible to trigger a `Handler` from thread whose runnable gets executed on main UI thread.

Comment: What do you mean by this: "I was thinking that is it possible to trigger a Handler from thread whose runnable gets executed on main UI thread"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I understood your problem completely, but I believe there are two ways to achieve what you want:

1- Start an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) instead of a thread. AsyncTask's `onPostExecute()` will [run in the UI thread](http://android-developers.blogspot.ca/2009/05/painless-threading.html), which means you can do anything UI-related in there. You can start the AsyncTask in onCreate(), and, once it finished, it calls a method on your activity which does:

```
myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

2- Use [runOnUIThread()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29)

Answer (score 0):

Use your Activity's `runOnUiThread(Runnable action)`

[link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29)